# Design an OWL DL ontology using Protoge

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege

I have to design an OWL DL ontology using protoge which  models the domain described with natural
language statements given below. Use class axioms and relations to other properties, e.g.
rdfs:subClassOf, owl:inverseOf and etc.

- Museum is a Building.
- Building consists of one or more Rooms.
- Room can have different room types, such as Museum Room, Conference Room, Hotel Room.
- Room is composed of Building Elements and Building Materials.
- Historical Exhibition is an individual of a Museum Room.
- Door, Window and Wall are Building Elements and compose a Room.
- Door is externally connected to some Wall or Window.
- The material type of a Window is one of Building Materials: Aluminum, Steel, Wood
- or Plastic.

However, I do not know how to do this. I tried but I have no clue if I am doing it right/ what I have to do different.

I added Building (with subclass Room whereby room has ubclasses Conference_Room, Hotel_Room, Museum_room), Building_elements (with subclasses Door, Wall, Window) , Building_material (with subclasses Aluminum, Plastic, Steel, Wood), Museum as classes

Next to that, I added Object properties:

1. Compose_a --> domains : Building_Elemens and Ranges : Rooms
2. Composed_of --> domains: Rooms, Ranges : Building_material, building_elements
3. Consists_of --> domains: Building, Ranges: Rooms
4. externally_connected_to --> domains = Door, Ranges : Wall, Window
5. is_and_individual  --> domains = Historical_exhibition, Ranges = Musem_Room

What am I doing wrong? I don't get a picture when I want to visualize in with OWLviz.
Thanks in Advance!
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMfoh.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HqGH.png)

Comment: I don't understand if the question is about your wrong domain model or why the Protege plugin doesn't show up ...

Comment: that said, there are some questionale decision, e.g. "I added Building (with subclass Room" - that would mean every room is a building, I don't think this is correct nor intended

Comment: "externally_connected_to --> domains = Door, Ranges : Wall, Window" - what does that means? any door is connected to a window? also, multiple ranges denote the intersection unless you did not say "wall or window" as a class expression

Comment: Your question really has two questions in it. Not seeing a picture in OWLViz might mean you don't have the utilities it relies on to draw (check the Protege console, there should be messages there). Whether the ontology is correct for your needs isn't an easy question to answer. UninformedUser has pointed out something that might be a mistake. Otherwise, I'd say you've built the ontology successfully, but can't tell if it's right for your task.

Comment: Thank you! The point is, I have no idea what I am doing nor what the result has to be. The only thing I know is that I have to design an owl ontology haha..  - do I have to enter room as a class? And how do I have to add the different room types? Next to that, how can I add the "Door is externally connected to some Wall or Window." in a correct way?

Comment: you could have a class for room and model the more specific rooms resp. the room types then as subclasses yes. I don't understand the phrase "externally connected", but at least you should not use multiple classes as range of a property as this semantically means the intersection of those classes. You have to use a union, i.e. in Protege you could use a class expression "Wall or Window" as the range of the property